# Using Zapier Code to Split a Full Name into First Name Last Name

Tags: zapier

We are using a webhook to pull data from Vimeo to Zapier and send it to our CRM (InfusionSoft).

I have no experience with coding and am having issues running a simple JS script in Zapier Code. The goal is to split up an embedded customer name, which comes as First and Last Name, into two outputs, First Name, Last Name.

The code that I found, and tried, from Zapier is this:

```
if ' ' in input['fullName']:
    first, last = input['fullName'].split(' ', 1)
else:
    first, last = input['fullName'], None # fallback
return {
    'firstName': first,
    'lastName': last
}
```

Any help here is greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Morgan

[Zapier Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDyKT.png)
[Error Returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dfvtu.png)

Comment: Your code looks like python code, you sure you want Javascript?

Comment: Your screenshot says the variable is called `inputData`.

Comment: I didn't know that was Python...such a newb! Thanks for your help Kevin!!

Comment: You are welcome mo_stacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the Javascript version of your code. You can just change null to whatever value you want in the else clause.

```
let first, last;
if ( input['fullName'].indexOf(" ") != -1 )
    [first, last] = input['fullName'].split(' ', 2);
else
    [first, last] = [input['fullName'], null];
return {
    'firstName': first,
    'lastName': last
}
```

For your later problem. I think it because you use this as raw and not in a function thus, I will write a fix for you. For Zapier, their document said all your values and variables start with inputData. So to apply the code above raw and not in a function call then you would have to do this.

```
if ( inputData.fullName ) {
    let first, last;
    if ( inputData['fullName'].indexOf(" ") != -1 )
        [first, last] = inputData['fullName'].split(' ', 2);
    else
        [first, last] = [inputData['fullName'], null];
    return {
        'firstName': first,
        'lastName': last
    }
} else {
    // inputData.fullName is not available, do something else.
}
```

If you are going to use it in a function call, then follow the below:

```
function getFullName(inputData) {
    var first, last;
    if ( inputData['fullName'].indexOf(" ") != -1 )
        [first, last] = inputData['fullName'].split(' ', 2);
    else
        [first, last] = [inputData['fullName'], null];
    return {
        'firstName': first,
        'lastName': last
    }
}

if ( inputData.fullName ) { 
   var someobject = getFullName(inputData);
} else {
   // no inputData.fullName
}
```

Comment: Hey @KevinNg this code was working initially but is now producing an error (not sure how that can happen) - saying "TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined"

I haven't altered the code at all...any ideas what may be the issue?

Thanks again for your help here!

Comment: @mo_stacks no worry, when there is a Type error. It may be because you passed it an undefined variable. Or an undefined index. If you show you a little bit more code I can help you. Also, do you want me to give you a faster code?

Comment: @mo_stack - sorry let me rephrase that sentence. If you show me a little bit more code ...

Comment: @mo_stacks I think I know the problem with your code. You have to use the inputData variable and not input. Besides that, you have to check if inputData fullName is available. So below my original I will give you a fix.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, just for future readers now that an answer is accepted.

```
var arr = inputData.fullName;
if (arr != undefined && arr != null) {
  var name = arr.concat(" ").split(' ');
  var i = 0;
    if (i < 2){
      name[i] = name[i]; 
      i++;
    }
  return {'firstName': name[0], 'lastName': name[1]};
} 
else {
  return {'firstName': 'N/A', 'lastName': 'N/A'} 
}
```

With this code you could tack on a middle name later on if needed. This also will check for `null` or zero values and provide a response (that you can edit as needed).

Secondly, you could have just used Zapier's Format action, run the text event and choose split on [:space:].

I realized that my first post had a typo with checking nulls that caused confusion (thanks Kevin for your input). It will certainly not be faster but it shouldn't error our on zapier regardless of the input.

Comment: Um, that is not faster, I tested it and you could simply just check for object length instead of doing all the undefined and null check. Also, I can't take credit for that, it mo_stack's method, I just simply translated it.

Comment: I bench-marked it and the average run over ten tests was faster (maybe I should run it through a different engine). But yes, it could be made faster with length(), however I was trying to account for length() being inserted by the CRM and Zapier as a possible null rather than a value of empty. Regardless, speed wasn't the point, both answers will do the job, just depends on how you want it done, one could have managed it without code just about as easily.

Comment: Just to prove my point though, I saved a fiddle of this at https://jsfiddle.net/kevinhng86/3cagr60j/. There are 3 methods there. You are right your code does run faster on FireFox but not on Chrome. However, method 3 is the fastest across all platform but method 1 is the most readable. You almost got your answer correctly though. I don't know why you ended up using the == undefined comparison.

Comment: Hey @littlecoder I've tried your code but the error that was returned is: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined" - any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: I would assume that is due to your defined variable name as that is the only way I could replicate what you mentioned. So, make sure that the zapier var you created is called `fullName` as you posted in your zapier code picture. If that doesn't solve it then I would need an updated pic of your input and code.

Comment: Kevin: I realized I made a typo in the null check. mo_stacks: Made some adjustments that should improve the function and prevent the undefined error (my goal to start with).